# Using a combo box as switch to load 2 different databases

Tags: vb.net

Hello I have a database management program in Visual Studio 2013 that I would like to use a combo box as a switch for loading one database or the other depending on the decision... I managed to do the switch but I am having several problems when editing the databases from VS 2013:

1. The information entered in those list(Add, Delete)don't update the Access Database, they just update on the datagrid of VS2013...
2. The DataGrid starts counting at -1 then -2 and so on...
3. When I hit the Edit button, the program returns me a OleDbException Unhandled...this exception states this : " An INSERT INTO query cannot contain a multi-valued field."

Here are my codes of the edit add and delete buttons respectively, what I am missing?

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox("Please specify a category first.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        ComboBox1.Focus()
    End If

    Me.Validate()
    Me.ContactsBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Database_de_EmpleadosDataSet)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    'category err
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox("Please specify a category first.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        ComboBox1.Focus()
    End If

    'codes for add a new field
    ContactsBindingSource.AddNew()
    'ContactsBindingSource1.AddNew()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    'code for err category
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox("Please specify a category first.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        ComboBox1.Focus()
    End If

    'code  for removing field/row
    ContactsBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
    ContactsBindingSource1.RemoveCurrent()
End Sub
```

And Here is how I made the switch in the combo box:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        Dim dbprovider As String = "PROVIDER = Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0;"
        Dim dbsource As String = "DATA SOURCE = \\Mac\Home\Desktop\Dalangs\Database De Empleados.accdb"
        DataGridView1.Show()
        DataGridView2.Hide()
        con.ConnectionString = dbprovider & dbsource
        con.Open()
        da.GetFillParameters()
        con2.Close()
        MsgBox("Employees successfully loaded")

    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
    Dim dbprovider As String = "PROVIDER = Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0;"
    Dim dbsource As String = "DATA SOURCE = \\Mac\Home\Desktop\Dalangs\Database De Clientes.accdb"
    DataGridView2.Show()
    DataGridView1.Hide()
        con2.ConnectionString = dbprovider & dbsource
        con2.Open()
        da2.GetFillParameters()
    con.Close()
    MsgBox("Clients successfully loaded")

    End If
    Button4.Visible = True
End Sub
```

what I am missing? :S

Comment: I cant see any code relating to SQL INSERT.  Not for nothing but one DB could store both sets of data.

Comment: You're using a `TableAdapterManager` to save changes. Are you changing the connection strings for the table adapters that it's managing?  Are `da1` and `da2` those table adapters or are they data adapters?

Comment: No, the codes da are data adapters, I just tried with the lines "da2.getfillparameters()" to see if that was the problem, but no....also @plutonix I know, one db could store both tables, but I was just trying to see if I could do it that way, using a switch for both databases, also I thought it was a sql insert, but that query should be done in the access db?

Comment: The error message posted indicates a SQL INSERT error, and it would show the exact line it fails on.  This code seems unrelated.  Of course, default control names dont help us understand whats what.  Button2 means nothing to us

Comment: button 5 is Edit, button 2 is Add and button 3 is Delete...also, the error doesn't present any line where it fails, that's why I was thinking maybe the problem or resriction is in the access database

Comment: Op, please learn proper naming convention. It will be helpful for you. I am sure, 5 days later, you won't remember whether button2 means Add or Delete.

Comment: right...I guess I'm kinda rusty..This is my first project since my second year of my degree....Ok fixed that and I'll guess I try using both tables on the same database, it's easier